# Can I use the MS Sync Framework 2.1 to sync database tables with Filestream enabled?

Tags: sql-server-2008, microsoft-sync-framework

Just wondering is there a way to sync tables between SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2005, having FILESTREAM enabled on few tables. Here I need to sync the table data along with the files saved on disk through FILESTREAM?

The scenario is like this:

I have 2 tables and both of them have one filed with XML datatype. Both the tables will have more than 200,000 records. Right now I am syncing these tables using MS Sync framework 2.1 and its syncing with no issues but takes way too long to finish syncing.

So I am thinking if I can enable FILESTREAM on the XML field and then sync along with the saved XML files on disk.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what performance gain in terms of sync would you get changing to a filestream. Filestream is a way for storing, you still have to serialize the XML data to the destination.

Have you tried tracing your sync to see where the bottleneck is? enabled batching? multiple scopes? etc...

Comment: Yes JuneT the bottleneck is while dealing with XML fields.